# Why I'm getting "topic quota exceeded" error in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send messages using conditions through Firebase Cloud Messaging, but it works sometimes because this random messages appears:

**Topic quota exceeded**

I've added an interval of 60 seconds between sends, but nothing works. Here's the payload:

```
{
"condition": "'topic1' in topics && !('topic2' in topics) && !('topic3' in topics)",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Foo",
        "body": "Bar"
    }
}
```

Any help is always welcome :)

Comment: There are documented limits for FCM. If you think they are being enforced incorrectly, Stack Overflow won't be able to help. You should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for that.

Comment: I think it's a bug related with conditions, because I use the same send interval (2 minutes) using topics and it works perfectly.

Comment: I forgot to sat that I'm using the Blaze plan.

Comment: If you think there is a bug in Firebase services, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.  Stack Overflow won't be able to help you.